How do I typeset sections similar to the Malaysian Penal Code?
I would like to typeset a document in the similar section formatting of the Malaysian Penal Code or other Malaysian laws. I am quite new to LaTeX, so I do not know how to directly edit sections etc. By the way, apologies if the question is phrased wrongly.
The Malaysian penal code has the following levels (as far as I know):

Chapters (in Roman numerals)
"Titles" Bolded text that somewhat categorizes sections (for example, a chapter titled "OFFENCES AFFECTING THE HUMAN BODY" has Offence Affecting Life)
Sections (they are slightly similar to simple numbered lists)
Subsections (appear similar to sections but have an alphabet beside it, eg 124K)

Lists are all in lowercase Roman lettering that are italicized and have brackets, eg (a).
An example of many of these sections are on pg79 of the Penal Code.
Links
Penal Code
Sorry if this question feels dumb.
Thank you for your time.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Which documentclass do you use? Which bib entries? etc. Please show us a short compilable TeX code you have so far ...

I'm still new to TeX, so I have not made any progress on the sectioning so far. But, I am using Overleaf with article class. I have no bib entries. Thanks for your comment
